# SEO messes with URL resulting in non working PHP plugin

Tags: php, joomla, seo

I am calling a PHP function by hitting a button in Joomla. This is the link of the button:

```
<a class="deleteNakladyButton" href="index.php?option=com_k2&amp;view=item&amp;task=deleteNaklady&amp;id=<?php echo $naklad->id?>&amp;cid=<?php echo $this->row->id; ?>"><?php echo JText::_('K2_DELETE'); ?></a>
```

$naklad->id is id of the row in database and $this->row->id is id of the item (article).

This is what non-SEO url looks like and it works:

```
http://localhost/web/index.php?option=com_k2&view=item&task=deleteNaklady&id=89&cid=1
```

This succesfully calls the functions and deletes the row from the database.

This is what SEO url looks like and it does not work:

```
 http://localhost/web/index.php/prubeh-stavby/item/deleteNaklady/89/1
```

When I hit the button with SEO turned on, I get 403 permission denied error. Is there some place in the code I can write either not to SEO optimize a specific URL? ANy other ideas are welcome! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you please try with `JRoute::_('')`

```
<a class="deleteNakladyButton" href="<?php JRoute::_('index.php?option=com_k2&view=item&task=deleteNaklady&id='.$naklad->id.'&cid='.$this->row->id.''); ?>"><?php echo JText::_('K2_DELETE'); ?></a>
```

Hope this will work....